# Parsing a delimited string into an array in Bash - why is "$var" different from $var though $var has no spaces?

Tags: bash, ifs

I am running Bash version 4.2.25.  Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

string="one:two:three:four"

# without quotes
IFS=: read -ra array_1 <<< $string
for i in "${array_1[@]}"; do printf "i = [$i]\n"; done
# output:
# i = [one two three four]

# with quotes
IFS=: read -ra array_2 <<< "$string"
for i in "${array_2[@]}"; do printf "i = [$i]\n"; done
# output:
# i = [one]
# i = [two]
# i = [three]
# i = [four]
```

What explains the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem on Linux with bash 4.2.46 and bash 4.3.30. However, here's an adapted version that does show the described behavior:

```
string="one:two:three:four"
IFS=:

read -ra array_1 <<< $string
for i in "${array_1[@]}"; do printf "i = [$i]\n"; done
# i = [one two three four]

read -ra array_2 <<< "$string"
for i in "${array_2[@]}"; do printf "i = [$i]\n"; done
# i = [one]
# i = [two]
# i = [three]
# i = [four]
```

This happens because variables are not actually split on spaces, they're split on `$IFS` (which defaults to space, tab and linefeed).

Since we've overridden `$IFS`, it's values with colons we have to be careful about quoting. Spaces no longer matter.

The source code shows that Bash [hardcodes a space](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c#n2460) in `string_list`, called through [write_here_string](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/redir.c#n328). When `IFS` does not include a space, a string that expands to multiple words will no longer be `read` into tokens along similar lines, making the difference more pronounced.

PS: This is a good example of why we should always quote our variables, even when we know what they contain.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug.  I looked back through [`CHANGES`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES) and couldn't find anything specific, but on cygwin bash 4.3.48(8), both quoted and unquoted give the expected output (four lines).  Sometime when I have bandwidth to burn I'll clone the [repo](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=bash) and blame [redir.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/redir.c#n317) to see if I can find some relevant commits.

Comment: This is indeed a bug that was partially addressed in 4.3 and completed(?) in 4.4.